# How can I execute the command in JOOQ with double select

Tags: jooq

I'm using code nerator!

I need to execute the following query:

```sql
SELECT sbcm_ref.process_time_reports_direct_buf_record((SELECT tr.time_reports_buf_id
FROM sbcm_buf.time_reports_direct_buf tr ORDERBY time_reports_buf_id desc limit 1
```

and this my command

```java
DSL.using(connection).select(Routines.processTimeReportsDirectBufRecord(select(TIME_REPORTS_DIRECT_BUF.TIME_REPORTS_BUF_ID).from(TIME_REPORTS_DIRECT_BUF).orderBy(TIME_REPORTS_DIRECT_BUF.TIME_REPORTS_BUF_ID.desc()).limit(1).fetch())).fetch();
```

where is mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can turn any `Select<R extends Record1<T>>` into a `Field<T>` by wrapping it with `DSL.field(Select)`:

```java
ctx.select(Routines.processTimeReportsDirectBufRecord(field(
    select(TIME_REPORTS_DIRECT_BUF.TIME_REPORTS_BUF_ID)
    .from(TIME_REPORTS_DIRECT_BUF)
    .orderBy(TIME_REPORTS_DIRECT_BUF.TIME_REPORTS_BUF_ID.desc())
    .limit(1)
))).fetch();
```

[See also the manual section about scalar subqueries](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/scalar-subqueries/). However, in this particular case, you don't need it. Why not just write:

```java
ctx.select(Routines.processTimeReportsDirectBufRecord(
        max(TIME_REPORTS_DIRECT_BUF.TIME_REPORTS_BUF_ID)
    ))
   .from(TIME_REPORTS_DIRECT_BUF)
   .fetch();
```